MGF for Unif(0,Gamma(2,\theta)
Let $X\sim Gam(2,\theta)$ and $Y\sim Uniform(0,x) $
Compute the pdf of $X|Y=y $ for $y>0 $ and $MGF_{XY}(t_1,t_2)$

$f_X(x)=x\cdot\frac{e^{-x/\theta}}{2\cdot \theta^2}$
$f_Y(y)=1/(x-0)=\frac{2\cdot \theta^2\cdot e^{x/\theta}}{x}$
Am I right? But I have no idea how could I get pdf of $X|Y=y $ and $ MGF_{XY}(t_1,t_2)$

Saying $f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)=\frac1{x-0}$ does not make it equal to $\frac1{f_X(x)}$.  You might instead want to use the joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ as an intermediate step (including the support) and then find $f_Y(y)$ by integrating over $x$, and finally  $f_{X\mid Y=y}(x)$

If $X$ is parametrized by shape and scale, then your expression for $f_X$ is correct.  But your density for $Y$ makes absolutely no sense.  I don't even know how you could have reasoned in such a manner.
First of all, it's algebraically wrong:  you write $f_Y(y)$, which is a function of $y$, but then you equate this to a function of $x$.  What happened to $y$?
Second, if $Y = 1/X$, that does not imply $f_Y = 1/f_X$.  This reflects a very basic misunderstanding of random variables and their probability distributions.  Any student who makes such an error would, in my opinion, need to review elementary probability theory from the beginning.
Third, $Y$ is not even equal to $1/X$.  It is instead conditionally uniform.  Think of the way a realization of $Y$ is generated as a two-step process:  first, you generate a realization of $X$ that follows a gamma distribution with shape $2$ and scale $\theta$.  Then you use this realization to generate a uniform random number $Y$ from the interval $[0,X]$.  The conditional density of $Y$ given $X$ is uniform, but the unconditional (marginal) density is what you would see if you repeated this two-step process for many independent drawings of $X$ and $Y$.  The correct expression for the unconditional density of $Y$ is
$$f_Y(y) = \int_{x=0}^\infty f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) f_X(x) \, dx,$$
where $f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) = \frac{1}{x} \mathbb 1(0 \le y \le x)$ is the conditionally uniform density of $Y$ given $X = x$, and $f_X(x)$ is the aforementioned gamma density for $X$.
The conditional density of $X$ given $Y = y$ is obtained via Bayes' rule:
$$f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y) = \frac{f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) f_X(x)}{f_Y(y)}.$$
The MGF is given by
$$M_{X,Y}(t_1, t_2) = \operatorname{E}[e^{t_1 X + t_2 Y}].$$
But again, in my opinion, you need to go back and review the basic theory before you even attempt such a calculation.

Thanks! $f_{Y} (y)=∫_{y}^{∞}{f_{Y|X} (y│x)⋅f_X (x)}dx=1/θ^2   ∫_{y}^{∞}{e^(-x/θ)} dx=e^{-y/θ)/θ}$
